# Convert FutureTask to ScheduledFuture

Tags: java, android, multithreading

For my android application I am planning to implement my own mechanism to schedule runnables ie., something like

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> runAfter(Runnable r, long millis) { 
  // Runs r after millis milliseconds. 
}
```

The problem I have is to create an instance of [ScheduledFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) which will be returned. Is there a way I could easily create instance of [ScheduledFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) which will allow tracking of the passed runnable.

Only way I know of is to implement my own [ScheduledFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) interface and create a wrapper for the submitted runnable which will set appropriate values on that implementation of the future, but I am looking for an easy way to do create ScheduledFuture instance for the given runnable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) as follow

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> runAfter(Runnable r, long millis) { 
   // Runs r after millis milliseconds.
   ScheduledExecutorService executor;
   return executor.schedule(r, millis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```